# Implementation of client side geocoding before form submission doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-api, geocoding

In my Rails application i want user to enter the address in the input field, then application should geocode it and send coordiates parameters on the server.

I have hidden fields for my computed latitude and longitude. I try to use JQuery so that when user submits the form it prevents default action, does geocoding logic, fills the hidden input fields and then actually submits the form.

Well, the problem is that something is wrong with my javascript code because geocoding doesn't work.

Here is my code:

views/locals/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @local  do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address, placeholder: "City, State or Postal Code"     %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :latitude %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :longitude %>
    <%= f.submit "Add local!", id: "submit_button" %>
<% end %>
```

assets/javascript/locals.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
    $('#new_local').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var address_to_geocode = document.getElementById('local_address').value();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({address: address_to_geocode },     function(results, status) {

            var coordinates = results[0].geometry.location;
            $("#local_latitude").val( coordinates.lat() );
            $("#local_longitude").val( coordinates.lng() );

        });
        $('#new_local').submit();
        })
    })
});
```

I have my API key included in application.html.erb.
Latitude and longitude are permitted in places controller.

Does anyone see where is the mistake?

Comment: Do you get any error? Also, you seem to reference something (probably you want the submit button) by id `#new_local` whereas the button in your template gets id `#submit_button`.

Comment: new_local is a form id

Comment: Then you should probably attach your geocoding code to the `submit` event, shouldn't you? You don't click on a form...

Comment: Right but still..both latitude and longitude are 0..

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try [geocomplete](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/)
or if you want to save your adress to db like lat/lon use 
[geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

`geocoded_by :full_street_address   # can also be an IP address
after_validation :geocode          # auto-fetch coordinates`

Comment: I'm not interested in server side geocoding